# PHP / Ajax / Jquery ? Keep polling external PHP script till it returns a value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a main.php page which I want to show a message like :  "Checking for completion.."

Main.php will keep calling (without leaving the page)  "function.php",

function.php returns with a boolean .

If function.php returns true: I want main.php to write that the operation completed if it returns false, it will need to keep checking untill it returns true.

I am unfamiliar with Ajax/JQuery but from what I understood it might be the best approach. Is someone able to provide me a (working) example of how to accomplish this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Ajax is what you want.  Ajax stands for asynchronous javascript and xml.  Jquery provides a wrapper for pure ajax, but you can run ajax via pure javascript. Take a look at this example. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function check(){
return $.ajax({
    url: 'function.php',
    type:'POST',
    success: function(risp){
        if(!risp){
            check();
        }else{
            alert("finished!!");
        }
    },
    failure: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
}

check();
```

Comment: I noticed that when it enters `else { alert("finished !"); }` the value of risp is lost (set to false). So if my script would '1' I can't further process that.  
How would I go about doing something like : 
i.e. `if (risp == '1'){ alert(risp); } }else{ check() }`

Comment: in your php use echo "finished"; and then use if(risp == "finished"){ .... }else{ check();  } .... or you wanna return a different value from finished??

Answer (score 1):

**main.php**

```
<script type="text/javasctipt">
   var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: {key1: value1, key2: value2},
          url: 'function.php',
          success: function(response){
              if(response == 'true'){
                   console.log('Operation Completed'); //<== Completed message use it as you want 
                   window.clearInterval(interval);
               }
          }
       });
    },2000);
</script>
```

Following script will give you a good idea about what you require. I will call function.php every 2 seconds.:

**function.php**

```
<?php

   //Do you processing
   $result = 'true';

   echo $result;

 ?>
```

Comment: This seems to come closest to what I need, after trying to run it (corrected the typo to javascript) it just keeps requesting function.php :
 
`var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'function.php',
          success: function(response){
              if(response == 'true'){
                   window.clearInterval(interval);
               }
          }
       });
    },2000);`

Any idea what might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1):

In summary: You main.php delivers HTML to a webbrowser.
In your HTML you write some JavaScript (using XHR/'AJAX') that will start polling the server to check if a certain process is completed.

The script on the server (functions.php) returns true or false to the client.
In case of false, you want to check again in, say 5 seconds.
Right?

If this is all new to you, you have a lot to dive into, but here are a few pointers:

[Good introduction to XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

[How to use window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

If you only want a true or false returnvalue, you don't have to use XML.
Just let the server return "true" or "false" as a string.

And last: Make sure your functions.php doesn't need to perform heavy operations to find out if the "process" is finished. If you do, you will put a lot of load on the server during the polling if you have many clients using the page.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution